# java string compareTo returns different result than equals

Tags: java, string

There is very strange behavior we see in our application.
We have this simple code:

```
public boolean isPrimitiveType()
{
    for (int i=0;i<m_primitiveTypes.length; i++)
    {
        if (m_type.compareTo(m_primitiveTypes[i]) == 0)
        {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            {
                log.fatal("isPrimitiveType() - type="+m_type+", checking with " + m_primitiveTypes[i] + " iteration " + i + " result " + m_type.compareTo(m_primitiveTypes[i]) + " array " 
            + Arrays.toString(m_primitiveTypes) + " with equals " + m_type.equals(m_primitiveTypes[i]));
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The array m_primitiveTypes is very simple:  [java.lang.String, boolean, int, long, float, short]

Types: m_primitiveTypes is String[], m_type is String.

What we see is that after some time (many calls to that method), we see wrong result - we call this method with "m_type" equals to "java.util.Vector", but it returns true although it should return false.
The fatal log from above shows this line:

```
2015-08-26 02:18:32,665 [WSM_REQUEST_SERVICE(1)(pid:14529)] FATAL com.intel.swiss.sws.mechanism.pxml.PXMLTag - isPrimitiveType() - type=java.util.Vector, checking with java.lang.String iteration 0 result 0 array [java.lang.String, boolean, int, long, float, short] with equals false
```

Which is very weird - seems like "java.util.Vector".compareTo("java.util.String") returns 0 while "java.util.Vector".equals("java.util.String") return false.

Maybe compareTo is not thread safe? As I said, this happens only after some running time and after many calls to that method was made. Also even after it happens, in some cases it works as expected.

Any guess to that mystery?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've created this class which isolates the code and still reproduces the problem:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PXMLTag 
{
public String m_type;
public static Random m_random = new Random();
private static String[] m_primitiveTypes = {"java.lang.String",
                                            "boolean",
                                            "int",
                                            "long",
                                            "float",
                                            "short"};

private static String[] m_allTypes = {"java.lang.String",
        "boolean",
        "int",
        "long",
        "float",
        "java.util.Vector",
        "java.util.Map",
        "short"};

public PXMLTag() 
{
    super();
}

public boolean isPrimitiveType()
{
    for (int i=0;i<m_primitiveTypes.length; i++)
    {
        String type = m_type;
        String primitiveType = m_primitiveTypes[i];
        if (type.compareTo(primitiveType) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int threads = 1;
    if (args.length == 1)
    {
        threads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }
    for (int i=0 ; i<threads ; i++)
    {
        Thread t = createThread();
        t.start();
    }
}

private static Thread createThread()
{
    return new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                PXMLTag tag = new PXMLTag();
                tag.m_type = getRandomType();
                if (tag.isPrimitiveType() && notReallyPrimitiveType(tag.m_type))
                {
                    System.out.println(tag.m_type + " not really primitive!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(m_random.nextInt(100));
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean notReallyPrimitiveType(String m_type)
        {
            return m_type.contains("Vector") || m_type.contains("Map");
        }

        private String getRandomType()
        {
            return m_allTypes[m_random.nextInt(m_allTypes.length)];
        }});
}
}
```

When running with 5 threads, the program stops (meaning - reproduces the issue) after 22 seconds:
time /usr/intel/pkgs/java/1.7.0.45-64/bin/java -jar /tmp/tag.jar 5
java.util.Vector not really primitive!
0.036u 0.012s 0:22.38 0.1%      0+0k 0+128io 0pf+0w

Even with one thread I was able to reproduce the problem:
time /usr/intel/pkgs/java/1.7.0.45-64/bin/java -jar /tmp/tag.jar 1
java.util.Vector not really primitive!
0.048u 0.012s 1:46.92 0.0%      0+0k 0+128io 0pf+0w

One more something i have discovered - on that problematic machine, with 5 threads - the program always stops after ~21-22 seconds, is that coincidence? I am suspecting some kind of JIT optimization maybe?
Any thoughts on that??

Response to Marco: I have added the prints you wanted and this is what I got:

This odd case

type 'java.util.Map'

currentPrimitiveType 'java.lang.String'

They are equal? false

They are compared 9

m_type 'java.util.Map'

m_primitiveType[i] 'java.lang.String'

They are equal? false

They are compared 9

java.util.Map not really primitive!

So the compare result is 9 but the prints are inside if clause that is only entered when the compare result is 0!

UPDATE 2:

Very interesting thing I found - running the same problem with -Xint (disabling hotspot compiler) does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: You'll see this if another thread modifies `m_type` from "`java.lang.String`" to "`java.util.Vector`" after the comparison... perhaps that's what's happening? It doesn't help that we don't have context here...

Comment: Code for your `m_type.equals()` and `m_type.toString()`? They are most likely violating their contract...

Comment: Your extract doesn't show the type for `m_type` and `m_primitiveTypes`. Are they really `java.lang.String` ?

Comment: Yes, m_type is just String, as well as the array.

Comment: Vector doesn't have a compareTo method, it's not Comparable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: `"java.util.Vector".compareTo("java.util.String")` returns 3, http://ideone.com/9Z7jRj It's thread safe as String is immutable.

Comment: Peter, I totally agree - but isn't my log shows different result? One possible solution i get from the comments here is that maybe m_type is changed during runtime. Look at the code it doesn't seem likely, but I will dig into this deeper

Comment: Note: `m_primitiveTypes[i]` ***is not*** thread safe.  It could be `"java.util.String"` when you do the compare but `"java.util.Vector"` in the print out.

Comment: No one change this array in the code...

Comment: Why are you using compare To and not equals in this code?
Can we see the definition of m_type & m_primitiveTypes.

Comment: I know I can use equals, but this is legacy code I am trying to debug. Changing this to equals might solve this case, but won't this issue surface in other places (potentially) to sorts strings?

Comment: @duduamar: You still haven't answered whether or not `m_type` might be modified...

Comment: @JonSkeet not according to what I see, but I am still trying to determine that for sure. According to my print it seems like it does not change.

Comment: `"java.util.Vector".compareTo("java.lang.String")` returns 9 :-). It it was a threading problem then `m_type` would have to change three times during method execution in order to produce the log output

Comment: @wero: Ah, good point - I'd missed that there was another `compareTo` call in the logging...

Comment: @duduamar which JVM do you use to run the application?

Comment: @wero java 1.7.0.45-64, which is working (the same code and same jvm) on all our other servers (even with the exact same OS)

Comment: *"the same code and same jvm"* - You mean the same program is showing this behavior only on *one* particular machine? Well, then I'd suggest to run a memory/RAM checker on the one where the bug appears...

Comment: @Marco13 indeed we also believe it's hardware issue, it just weird it causes this weird behavior.